# After sudo-apt update/upgrade realm-object-server won't run

Tags: realm, ubuntu-16.04, realm-mobile-platform

I installed realm-object0server on `Ubuntu 16.04` few days ago, and implemented iOS app which successfully syncs with it. I was also able to connect to dashboard through Safari. But after I made some changes, like updating `OpenSSL` and `Curl` libs, also `apt-get update/upgrade` it stops working.
I'm not really sure on what exact step it stops working, but the fact is that I can not start it anymore, as it crashes every time:

```
$ sudo systemctl start realm-object-server
$ sudo systemctl status realm-object-server
● realm-object-server.service - Realm Sync Services
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/realm-object-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: signal) since Thu 2016-11-03 21:32:24 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 2203 ExecStart=/usr/bin/realm-object-server -c /etc/realm/configuration.yml (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 2203 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Nov 03 21:32:24 ubuntu-01 systemd[1]: realm-object-server.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Nov 03 21:32:24 ubuntu-01 systemd[1]: realm-object-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 03 21:32:24 ubuntu-01 systemd[1]: realm-object-server.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Nov 03 21:32:24 ubuntu-01 systemd[1]: realm-object-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 03 21:32:24 ubuntu-01 systemd[1]: Stopped Realm Sync Services.
Nov 03 21:32:24 ubuntu-01 systemd[1]: realm-object-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 03 21:32:24 ubuntu-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Realm Sync Services.
```

configuration.yml is correct, I checked it as its described in official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue in the upgrade process at the moment. We are working on a fix, which should be coming out in the next few days. This issue is tracked here: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/35.

In the meantime, if you don't have any users, the simplest way is to wipe the data directory and start from scratch (I know it's not a solution, but just to "unblock" you).

In order to wipe the server, simply run:

```
sudo service realm-object-server stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/realm/object-server
sudo service realm-object-server start
```

Comment: Ok, but please clarify how to correctly wipe data directory on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I've added that now.